# Ajax update element with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I managed to automatically give a different id to my divs

I have  the following

```
<diw class="ajaxlink">
     <div id="post1">  
     </div>

     ..link  1 ...
</div>
<div class="ajaxlink>
     <div id="post2">
     </div>
     ...link 2 ...
</div>
```

I want to update a specific div

by selecting  the div in the following way

when I click to the link 1,  I launched a jquery which

display the correct  id  ,

if I click the link 1,  my command

```
alert($(".ajaxlink > :first-child").attr("id"));
```

display post1

if I click the link 2,  my command display post2

Fine.

but when I use the update option

```
'update'=>'.ajaxlink > :first-child'
```

it updates the  post1 and post2 div,  where it should update the selected post, the alert displays the correct name of the id  (post1 or post2)

Here is the code

```
<div class="ajaxlink">
        <?php echo "<div id='post".$data->id."'>...</div>";  ?>
        <?php           

            echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
            'Test request',          
            array($url_replace),
            array(
            'update'=>'.ajaxlink > :first-child' ,
            'beforeSend' => 'function() {  
               alert($(".ajaxlink > :first-child").attr("id"));  //alert post 1 if I'm in post 1..

            }',

            )
            );


        ?>
    </div>
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: "if I click the link 1, my command display post1

if I click the link 2, my command display post2" Are you sure???

Comment: A JSfiddle would help make things clearer. For example, what's the code for the update?

Comment: I added the code to the post  @towr

Comment: But here, `alert($(".ajaxlink > :first-child").attr("id"));` will always return `post1`. Where is the click handler? WHat is `CHtml::ajaxLink()`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: `CHtml::ajaxLink()` seems to come from [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the postid, I'd say just use that to form the update ajaxLink:

```
<div class="ajaxlink">
    <?php echo "<div id='post".$data->id."'>...</div>";  ?>
    <?php
        echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
            'Test request',          
            array($url_replace),
            array(
                'update'=>'#post'.$data->id,
                'beforeSend' => 'function() {  
                    alert($("#post'.$data->id.'").attr("id"));
                }',
            )
        );
    ?>
</div>
```